# Visual studio not running DELETE command-line statements MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hey guys hoping somebody can help me out with some mysql/visual basic not deleting rows when running delete statements through visual basic methods but the same statement is operational in command-line sql here is the VB statement:

```
 public void removeBookFromCollection(int bookID)   
 {
     try{
         conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
         conn.Open();
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM books WHERE Id=" + bookID;
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleted book :" + bookID);
        }
 }
```

After activating this method several times through the use of a test form button I used cmd mysql to check if it updated mydb and it hadn't <"SELECT * FROM books">

I then ran the exact same delete statement through command-line and it worked with no errors I was wondering if somebody can help me working the statement through VB Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `ExecuteNonQuery` method to actually run the command from your code. The solution to your is to modify it as follows:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs)
{
  conn.Open();        
  MySqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM books WHERE Id=" + bookID;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleted book :" + bookID);
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is a method that's inbuilt. You can refer to the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executenonquery